# removing parameters from url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to remove a parameter after the true url then redirection to the same url without this parameter

example :

i want to remove the parameter "r" from

```
http://www.mysite.com/123.html?r=1
```

and redirection to

```
http://www.mysite.com/123.html
```

using htaccess and 301 redirect

thank you

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^123.html.? 123.html? [L]
```

Note how the second url ends with a `?`, this removes the query string.

Source: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Answer (score 2):

Better than using a final `?`, you should use the [qsdiscard](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/fr/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag `QSD`, and the permanent [redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/fr/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag `R=301`. So for your example :

```
RewriteRule ^123\.html(.*)$ 123.html [QSD,L,R=301]
```