# rewrite rule remove ugly code

Tags: .htaccess, url

i have reading different post but was't able to implement on my htaccess.

i have a url when i search on the page i get this url http://doman.se/module/spsearchpro/catesearch?fc=module&module=spsearchpro&controller=catesearch&orderby=name&orderway=desc&cat_id=2%2C4%2C9%2C6%2C5%2C10%2C8%2C7%2C11%2C36%2C37%2C50%2C21%2C29%2C22%2C24%2C23%2C53%2C31%2C30%2C32%2C52%2C12%2C13%2C39%2C25%2C14%2C33%2C34%2C43%2C35%2C44%2C40%2C51%2C15%2C16%2C20%2C19%2C41%2C49%2C42%2C46%2C45%2C48%2C27%2C38%2C28%2C47%2C54%2C55%2C56&search_query=general&spr_submit_search=Search&n=30

how can i remove the numbers 2%2C4%2C9%2C6%2C5%2C10%2C8%2C7%2C11%2C36%2C37%2C50%2C21%2C29%2C22%2C24%2C23%2C53%2C31%2C30%2C32%2C52%2C12%2C13%2C39%2C25%2C14%2C33%2C34%2C43%2C35%2C44%2C40%2C51%2C15%2C16%2C20%2C19%2C41%2C49%2C42%2C46%2C45%2C48%2C27%2C38%2C28%2C47%2C54%2C55%2C56

or make the url like this 
http://doman.se/search_query=general

Comment: the numbers you refer to are URL-encoded . 
post the url in http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
and click on the decode button

Comment: this will only remove the %2C and the id will be left, what i want is to rewrite the url

Comment: follow the example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537281/removing-parameters-from-url
and refer to 
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

`RewriteRule ^/module/spsearchpro/catesearch /?search_query=general`